# Distinguish between Root CA and Intermediate CA Certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, x509certificate2

I have managed to figure out if a cert in a x509Certificate2Collection is a certificate authority cert but how can I safely determine if it's a Root cert or an Intermediate cert please? Is the following safe enough?

```
var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import("test.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
{
    var basicConstraintExt = cert.Extensions["2.5.29.19"] as X509BasicConstraintsExtension;
    if (basicConstraintExt != null)
    {
        Log.Debug($"    Subject is: '{cert.Subject}'");
        Log.Debug($"    Issuer is: '{cert.Issuer}'");
        if (basicConstraintExt.CertificateAuthority)
        {
            Log.Debug("I am a CA Cert.");
            if (cert.Subject == cert.Issuer)
            {
                Log.Debug("My Subject matches Issuer.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Debug("My Subject does not match Issuer.");
            }
            Log.Debug(cert.Verify() ? "I verify" : "I do not verify");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Debug("I am not a CA Cert.");
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
 Displaying Cert #1 in collection
 ********************************

 Subject is: 'CN=Intermediate-CA, DC=test, DC=lan'
 Issuer is: 'CN=Root-CA, DC=test, DC=lan'
 - I am a CA Cert.
 - My Subject does not match Issuer.
 - I do not verify


 Displaying Cert #2 in collection
 ********************************

 Subject is: 'CN=Root-CA, DC=test, DC=lan'
 Issuer is: 'CN=Root-CA, DC=test, DC=lan'
 - I am a CA Cert.
 - My Subject matches Issuer.
 - I do not verify
```

Comment: You could also check the signature. RootCA is self signed. So if you verify the signature of the certificate using the public key in the same certificate it should tell you is it is self signed. And if the subject DN and issuer DN matches and it is a CA then you have found your RootCA.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Do I have to use something like BouncyCastle to get the Signature?! :-/

Comment: You can use `X509Certificate2.Verify()` to verify the signature. You don't need to use BC for that. It does the trust check as well.

Comment: Also, I would note that provided code is ineffective and error-prone on localized (non-English) systems.

Comment: Thanks v.much @Crypt32 I will change to searching by Oid.value so it is not restricted to English.   How do I used Verify() to determine if it is self signed? I have try understanding this via the MS documentation but it's not clear for me.

Comment: Your inner loop can be simplified with: `var bcext = cert.Extensions["2.5.29.19"] as X509BasicConstraintsExtension;` Then check if `bcext` variable is null and take additional actions.

Comment: `X509Certificate2.Verify` will perform signature check. You can manually check if subject matches issuer and Verify() will verify trust and signature.

Comment: Hi @Crypt32 I've updated my post with my current findings but the root cert doesn't verify?!  I am hoping to identify root cert, and add it to the Root store.

Comment: it seems that root CA is not trusted. Ok, can you provide your final goal? You've got a PFX with multiple certificates, what is your end goal? Maybe I can provide a better solution?

Comment: Hi, @Crypt32 - So what the original problem is, is that the SSL certificate I am securing my Kestrel web api app with, is signed by an Intermediate CA.  For whatever reason, Kestrel /.Net Core on Linux, does not responde with the Intermediate CA (it responds with just the leaf) on SSL handshake unless the Intermediate CA and Trusted Root Cert is added to the store.  So, I am trying to add the collection of certs in the PFX that are CAs to the correct store, so that my SSL cert can be verified as valid when client requests it.

Comment: The issue I have mentioned is here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10971

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps with Kestrel, but I would try the code below.

We will use [X509Chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain) class to construct and validate the chain.

```
var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import("test.pfx", "password");

var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(collection);
// untrusted root error raise false-positive errors, for example RevocationOffline
// so skip possible untrusted root chain error.
chain.VerificationFlags |= X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
// revocation checking is client's responsibility. Skip it.
chain.RevocationMode = X509VerificationFlags.NoCheck;
// build the chain.
Boolean isValid = chain.Build(collection[0]);
// explore chain.ChainElements collection. First item should be your leaf
// certificate and last item should be root certificate
```

All this stuff is located in `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` namespace. In this code piece, I'm assuming that first certificate in PFX is leaf certificate (it is in 99% cases unless someone tries to ignore standards). By exploring `chain.ChainElements` collection, you can find issues with every certificate in the chain.